# Discord.js - TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'username')

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

*victim* is a string where i input the user's id. I've checked and it is a valid ID of a user in the server and yet i get the error 'cannot read properties of undefined'

I've used `client.users.cache.get(victim).username` in another code block but this is the first instance of it

````js
const victim = interaction.options.get("user").value
const reason = interaction.options.get("reason").value
const time = Date.now()
                
client.guilds.cache.get("808701451399725116").channels.cache.get("858644165038047262").send({ 
                    embeds: [
                        new EmbedBuilder()
                            .setTitle("New Blacklist")
                            .setFields(
                                {
                                    name:"User",
                                    value:`Name: **${client.users.cache.get(victim).username}*** \n`+ `Discrim: **${client.users.cache.get(victim).discriminator}** \n` + `User Id: **${victim}**`,
                                    inline: true
                                },
                                {
                                    name:"Reason",
                                    value:`${reason}`,
                                    inline: true
                                },
                                {
                                    name: "Time (epoch)",
                                    value: `${time}`
                                }
                            )
                            .setThumbnail(client.users.cache.get(victim).avatarURL())
                            .setImage("https://cdn.discordapp.com/emojis/860970578684018700.webp?size=160&quality=lossless")
                    ]
                });
    ```
````

Comment: Have you considered an issue with partials and fetching perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user (victim) is not cached. You can instead fetch the user

```js
let VictimUser = await client.users.fetch(victim)
console.log(VictimUser.username)
```